# React-table and go to first/last page

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to add "go to" first/last page buttons to the React-Table by overwriting `PreviousComponent` and `NextComponent` but it looks like both components are connected to the previous/next page functionality behaviours.

Is there any other way to add those two buttons to the default pagination component?

Comment: instead of << and >> you need the text as First and Last is that what you are looking for

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I need functionality for both next/previous as well << and >>

Comment: so basically how it is working for first and last it should work also instead of showing in the Ui as << and >> it should be First and Last

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS so you are saying that `PreviousComponent` and `NextComponent` will replace only presentation part not functionality?

Comment: Will this work for you, https://codesandbox.io/s/59580560-so-custom-text-for-first-and-last-react-table-inddd. let me know so i will add it

Comment: Check the codesandbox if it works for you let me know it

Comment: Happy to help, Kindly check the answer :)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yeah - perfect example but it looks like v7 when I'm still on v6

Comment: You can update the version, I didn't checked much on the version side, but you will have support on this. Anyways happy to help :) If it worked for you kindly vote and accept so it will be helpful for others

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I have tried but hit blockers which made it v6 porting to v7 problematic

Comment: Which version are you using exactly of v6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205304/discussion-between-jacktheknife-and-dileep-thomas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For v6 I have ended up overwriting `PaginationComponent`

```
<ReactTable 
  ....
  PaginationComponent={PaginationComponent}
  ....
>
```

with modified default code as custom `PaginationComponent` where I have added

```
            <div className="-first">
                <button
                    disabled={!canPrevious}
                    onClick={() => {
                        if (!canPrevious) return
                        this.changePage(0)
                    }}
                > First </button>
            </div>
```

and

```
            <div className="-last">
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        if (!canNext) return
                        this.changePage(pages)
                    }}
                    disabled={!canNext}
                > Last </button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can customise the text as required. I have mocked the data, you can pass the actual data as required

See the code

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useTable, usePagination } from "react-table";

import makeData from "./makeData";

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }

  .pagination {
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
`;

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page, // Instead of using 'rows', we'll use page,
    // which has only the rows for the active page

    // The rest of these things are super handy, too ;)
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize }
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      initialState: { pageIndex: 2 }
    },
    usePagination
  );

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {/* 
        Pagination can be built however you'd like. 
        This is just a very basic UI implementation:
      */}
      <div className="pagination">
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {"First"}
        </button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {"<"}
        </button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {">"}
        </button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {"Last"}
        </button>{" "}
        <span>
          Page{" "}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{" "}
        </span>
        <span>
          | Go to page:{" "}
          <input
            type="number"
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={e => {
              const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0;
              gotoPage(page);
            }}
            style={{ width: "100px" }}
          />
        </span>{" "}
        <select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={e => {
            setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "First Name",
            accessor: "firstName"
          },
          {
            Header: "Last Name",
            accessor: "lastName"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Header: "Info",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Age",
            accessor: "age"
          },
          {
            Header: "Visits",
            accessor: "visits"
          },
          {
            Header: "Status",
            accessor: "status"
          },
          {
            Header: "Profile Progress",
            accessor: "progress"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(100000), []);

  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </Styles>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59580560-so-custom-text-for-first-and-last-react-table-inddd)

Comment: Good example for v7. Looking to get the same for v6

Comment: Happy to help :)